# Using AWS es using Springboot elasticSearchClient

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

I am trying to connect to AWS es and perform queries using elasticSearchClient.
But as it seems like AWS doesn't work with transport client and the alternate for transport client `RestHighLevelClient` is also being deprecated.

So this is the implementation i found for the new elasticSearchClient using AWS

```
@Bean
public ElasticsearchClient elasticsearchClient() {
        AWS4Signer signer = new AWS4Signer();
        String serviceName = "es";
        signer.setServiceName(serviceName);
        signer.setRegionName("region");
        HttpRequestInterceptor interceptor = new AWSRequestSigningApacheInterceptor(serviceName, signer, "credentialsProvider");
        RestClient restClient = RestClient.builder(HttpHost.create("endpoint")).setHttpClientConfigCallback(e -> e.addInterceptorLast(interceptor)).build();

        ElasticsearchTransport transport = new RestClientTransport(
                restClient, new JacksonJsonpMapper());

        ElasticsearchClient client = new ElasticsearchClient(transport);
        
        return client;
}
```

where `ElasticsearchClient` is instance of `co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch`.
Before this i was using the `org.elasticsearch.client.Client`.
The `co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchClient` seems to have lesser functions then `org.elasticsearch.client.Client`.
**How can i migrate from the older client to the newer one?**
I can't seem to find any documentation for `co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch`.
Any article/tutorial will be of great help.

Things like client.prepareSearch have been removed and i can't find a properly documented alternate.
The documentation persent at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api-client/current/java-client-javadoc.html
is useless as it's an autogenerated one.

Comment: Check this out : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api-client/current/migrate-hlrc.html#migrate-hlrc

Comment: @NishikantTayade This is literally the code i have posted in the question.
I need the docs for further removed functions like prepareSearch etc. which have been changed or removed